# Setting up SPI with sam4s16c

Tags: spi, programming, atmel

I started programmer for Software and have a professional background with large software projects in c++ and QT. Now I changed the company and also have to write some low level hardware code and i have some starting trouble, messing around with tones of datasheets.
I am new to hardware programming in general and don't know much about tools or how can i help myself.

My plan is to start communication with a [Sam4s16c](http://www.atmel.com/devices/ATSAM4S16C.aspx?tab=tools) (on a [SAM4SXplained board](http://www.atmel.com/webdoc/sam4s16xplained/index.html)) to a [L6470](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/a5/86/06/1c/fa/b2/43/db/CD00255075.pdf/files/CD00255075.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00255075.pdf) motor via SPI.
My problem is that the SPI setup gives me headache and will not work.
Measuring the CS/SS (pin31A) an oscilloscope will only show high voltage (~3,2V) but no valid clock (I should see an "up and down" here, or not?).

I am not sure what is a good value for the baudrate divider (and what it means in general)
After a lot of reading i heard i have to "configure" the pins correctly, i tried this with this lines

```
gpio_configure_pin(SPI_NPCS1_PA31_GPIO, SPI_NPCS1_PA31_FLAGS);
gpio_set_pin_high(SPI_NPCS1_PA31_GPIO);
```

My code so far.

```
#include "asf.h"
#include "stdio_serial.h"
#include "conf_board.h"
#include "conf_clock.h"
#include "conf_spi_example.h"

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

/* Chip select. */
#define SPI_CHIP_SEL 0
#define SPI_CHIP_PCS spi_get_pcs(SPI_CHIP_SEL)

/* Clock polarity. */
#define SPI_CLK_POLARITY 1

/* Clock phase. */
#define SPI_CLK_PHASE 1

/* Delay before SPCK. */
//#define SPI_DLYBS 0x40
#define SPI_DLYBS 0xFF

/* Delay between consecutive transfers. */
#define SPI_DLYBCT 0x10

/* SPI clock setting (Hz). */
static uint32_t gs_ul_spi_clock = 1000000;


volatile uint32_t g_ul_ms_ticks = 0;
void SysTick_Handler(void)
{
    g_ul_ms_ticks++;
}
static void mdelay(uint32_t ul_dly_ticks)
{
    uint32_t ul_cur_ticks;

    ul_cur_ticks = g_ul_ms_ticks;
    while ((g_ul_ms_ticks - ul_cur_ticks) < ul_dly_ticks);
}


/**
 * \brief Initialize SPI as master.
 */
static void spi_master_initialize(void)
{
    //Assign I/O lines to peripheral
    #define SPI_MISO_IOPIN  IOPORT_CREATE_PIN(PIOA, PIO_PA12_IDX)
    #define SPI_MOSI_IOPIN  IOPORT_CREATE_PIN(PIOA, PIO_PA13_IDX)
    #define SPI_SPCK_IOPIN  IOPORT_CREATE_PIN(PIOA, PIO_PA14_IDX)
    #define SPI_NPCS1_IOPIN  IOPORT_CREATE_PIN(PIOA, PIO_PA31_IDX)

    ioport_set_pin_mode(SPI_MISO_IOPIN, PIO_PERIPH_A);
    ioport_disable_pin(SPI_MISO_IOPIN);
    ioport_set_pin_mode(SPI_MOSI_IOPIN, PIO_PERIPH_A);
    ioport_disable_pin(SPI_MOSI_IOPIN);
    ioport_set_pin_mode(SPI_SPCK_IOPIN, PIO_PERIPH_A);
    ioport_disable_pin(SPI_SPCK_IOPIN);
    ioport_set_pin_mode(SPI_NPCS1_IOPIN, PIO_PERIPH_A);
    ioport_disable_pin(SPI_NPCS1_IOPIN);

    /* Configure an SPI peripheral. */
    spi_enable_clock(SPI_MASTER_BASE);
    spi_disable(SPI_MASTER_BASE);
    spi_reset(SPI_MASTER_BASE);
    spi_set_lastxfer(SPI_MASTER_BASE);
    spi_set_master_mode(SPI_MASTER_BASE);
    spi_disable_mode_fault_detect(SPI_MASTER_BASE);
    spi_set_peripheral_chip_select_value(SPI_MASTER_BASE, spi_get_pcs(SPI_CHIP_PCS));
    spi_set_fixed_peripheral_select(SPI_MASTER_BASE);
    spi_set_delay_between_chip_select(SPI_MASTER_BASE, 0);

    // Set the Chip Select register
    spi_set_transfer_delay(SPI_MASTER_BASE, SPI_CHIP_SEL, SPI_DLYBS, SPI_DLYBCT);

    int16_t baudrate = spi_calc_baudrate_div(96000, sysclk_get_cpu_hz());
    spi_set_baudrate_div(SPI_MASTER_BASE, SPI_CHIP_SEL, 8); //sysclk_get_cpu_hz() / gs_ul_spi_clock);
    spi_set_bits_per_transfer(SPI_MASTER_BASE, SPI_CHIP_SEL, SPI_CSR_BITS_8_BIT);
    //spi_configure_cs_behavior(SPI_MASTER_BASE, SPI_CHIP_SEL, SPI_CS_RISE_NO_TX);
    spi_set_clock_polarity(SPI_MASTER_BASE, SPI_CHIP_SEL, SPI_CLK_POLARITY);
    spi_set_clock_phase(SPI_MASTER_BASE, SPI_CHIP_SEL, SPI_CLK_PHASE);

    spi_enable(SPI_MASTER_BASE);

    mdelay(100);
}

static void spi_master_write(uint16_t value)
{
    spi_write(SPI_MASTER_BASE, value, SPI_CHIP_SEL, 0);
    while ((spi_read_status(SPI) & SPI_SR_RDRF) == 0);/* Wait transfer done. */
}

static spi_status_t spi_master_read(uint16_t* data)
{
    uint8_t uc_pcs;

    spi_status_t returnValue = spi_read(SPI_MASTER_BASE, data, &uc_pcs);
    return returnValue;
}

static void ledHello(void)
{
    for (int i=0; i < 6; ++i)
    {
        LED_Toggle(LED0_GPIO);
        LED_Toggle(LED1_GPIO);
        mdelay(150);
    }
    mdelay(150);

    for (int i=0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        LED_Toggle(LED0_GPIO);
        mdelay(150);
    }

    for (int i=0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        LED_Toggle(LED1_GPIO);
        mdelay(150);
    }
    // Both LEDs stay permanent on
}

int main(void)
{
    board_init();
    sysclk_init();

    NVIC_DisableIRQ(SPI_IRQn);
    NVIC_ClearPendingIRQ(SPI_IRQn);
    NVIC_SetPriority(SPI_IRQn, 0);
    NVIC_EnableIRQ(SPI_IRQn);

    // [main_step_systick_init]
    if (SysTick_Config(sysclk_get_cpu_hz() / 1000)) {
        // Systick configuration error
        while (1);
    }

    ledHello(); // Code here toggles leds on board

    /* Configure SPI as master, set up SPI clock. */
    spi_master_initialize();

    // activate the SPI of the micro controller of the L6470 via SPI
    spi_master_write(0x18); // SetParam(Config)
    spi_master_write(0x16);
    spi_master_write(0x10);

    mdelay(100);
    while (1) {
        spi_master_write(0x38); // GetParam(Config)
        static uint16_t data;
        spi_master_read(data);
        spi_master_read(data);
    }
}

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

At the moment i try to setup the spi clock / output correctly. Did i miss something?

Comment: after @Tom L. helped me with the pin configuration, my Clock works, but has some "hickups" (what is the professional word for this?). It shows 8 pulses, than a break for about 6 pulses, then starting again with 8. very regularly. Any idea about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the GPIO setup. You MUST NOT assign the GPIO function but you need to tell the pin which alternate function it actually has. This will be something along the lines:

```
#define SPI_SO_PIN                      PIN_PC28B_SPI_MISO  
#define SPI_SO_MUX                      MUX_PC28B_SPI_MISO  
#define SPI_SI_PIN                      PIN_PC29B_SPI_MOSI  
#define SPI_SI_MUX                      MUX_PC29B_SPI_MOSI  
#define SPI_SCK_PIN                     PIN_PC30B_SPI_SCK   
#define SPI_SCK_MUX                     MUX_PC30B_SPI_SCK   
#define SPI_CS0_PIN                     PIN_PC31B_SPI_NPCS0 
#define SPI_CS0_MUX                     MUX_PC31B_SPI_NPCS0 

#define ioport_set_pin_peripheral_mode(pin, mode) \
do {\
    ioport_set_pin_mode(pin, mode);\
    ioport_disable_pin(pin);\
} while (0)

ioport_set_pin_peripheral_mode(SPI_SCK_PIN, SPI_SCK_MUX);
ioport_set_pin_peripheral_mode(SPI_SO_PIN, SPI_SO_MUX);
ioport_set_pin_peripheral_mode(SPI_SI_PIN, SPI_SI_MUX);
ioport_set_pin_peripheral_mode(SPI_CS0_PIN, SPI_CS0_MUX);
```

Atmel has a pretty good example repository. Start Atmel Studio, select new example project, select your controller or board and load something related to the component you're implementing (SPI in your case). Then follow "main" until you get to the point you're interested in. From there on it's usually easy going.

If a pin won't move for whatever reason, the best guess is that you have your GPIO (or alternate ping configuration) setup wrong.

It seems the SAM4S is a little different from the SAM4L. If you take a look at the supplied SPI example from the ASF, you will see the init sequence (function board_init() in SPI_EXAMPLE1\src\ASF\sam\boards\sam4s_ek\init.c) as:

```
/* Configure an SPI peripheral. */
spi_enable_clock(SPI_MASTER_BASE);
spi_disable(SPI_MASTER_BASE);
spi_reset(SPI_MASTER_BASE);
spi_set_lastxfer(SPI_MASTER_BASE);
spi_set_master_mode(SPI_MASTER_BASE);
spi_disable_mode_fault_detect(SPI_MASTER_BASE);
spi_set_peripheral_chip_select_value(SPI_MASTER_BASE, SPI_CHIP_PCS);
spi_set_clock_polarity(SPI_MASTER_BASE, SPI_CHIP_SEL, SPI_CLK_POLARITY);
spi_set_clock_phase(SPI_MASTER_BASE, SPI_CHIP_SEL, SPI_CLK_PHASE);
spi_set_bits_per_transfer(SPI_MASTER_BASE, SPI_CHIP_SEL, SPI_CSR_BITS_8_BIT);
spi_set_baudrate_div(SPI_MASTER_BASE, SPI_CHIP_SEL, (sysclk_get_peripheral_hz()/ gs_ul_spi_clock));
spi_set_transfer_delay(SPI_MASTER_BASE, SPI_CHIP_SEL, SPI_DLYBS, SPI_DLYBCT);
spi_enable(SPI_MASTER_BASE);

gpio_configure_pin(SPI_MISO_GPIO, SPI_MISO_FLAGS);
gpio_configure_pin(SPI_MOSI_GPIO, SPI_MOSI_FLAGS);
gpio_configure_pin(SPI_SPCK_GPIO, SPI_SPCK_FLAGS);
gpio_configure_pin(SPI_NPCS0_GPIO, SPI_NPCS0_FLAGS);
```

To actually talk to a device you will need to select that device (this is what spi_set_peripheral_chip_select_value does, it also includes logic if you have a DEMUX on board that's why it uses the spi_get_pcs macro). Since SPI_CHIP_SEL is 0, you will talk to whatever device is connected to CS0. If you want to talk to a device on a different chip select line, you will need to modify these values and your GPIO setup accordingly.

Your first task is to get the chip select line low. Unless this is done, you will never receive any data from the slave because it thinks that you're not talking to him but to some other device on the same SPI bus.

Comment: thank you, this gives me a huge break through. Now I can see my clock with the oscilloscope. Also writing data looks pretty good now. Just reading data receives 0x00 every time.

Comment: now i try to use the loopback `spi_enable_loopback(SPI_MASTER_BASE)` mode to track down my data, but i still received 0x00. looks like some configuration is also wrong

Comment: Did you check that if your MISO/SO line actually contains data? Does your CS line go low correctly? Show us the code you have so far - probably you forgot to assert CS. Did you check that you have the correct pins setup?

Comment: i updated my code with GPIO setup, slave initialization and reading config from slave in while loop. I couldn't test your GPIO setup, i am missing of the `PIN_PC31B_SPI_NPCS0`PIN_PC31B_SPI_NPCS0`defines (like in my code, they named slightly different, but i can't find out an equivalent variable for the `MUX_`). And yes, my CS line is not changing. MISO/SO line looks fine.

Comment: ´#define SPI_CHIP_SEL 0
#define SPI_CHIP_PCS spi_get_pcs(SPI_CHIP_SEL)` what is about this definitions? atmel studio tells me that SPI_CHIP_PCS = 14. Is this "value" the pin of my CS? I mean my CS pin PA31.

Comment: Nope, you're doing it wrong :-). Go to the datasheet of your controller, check out the GPIO table at the beginning (a large, 3 or 4 page long table). It lists the pin ident such as PA31 and next to it, it lists its functions (around page 52 - PIO Controller A Multiplexing).

Comment: I'll add something to my main post

Comment: On the [sam4s xplained board I used the expansion header 1[(http://www.atmel.com/webdoc/sam4s16xplained/sam4s16xplained.Connectors.section_uhn_bzg_xf.html) which is connected to cs1 aka PA31 (takes me ages to find out). Changing `#define SPI_CHIP_SEL 0` to `#define SPI_CHIP_SEL 1` in code fixes this. so mutch small steps to walk :)  thanks for your tips and help. I mark your answer as correct

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working. Yes, it takes a while to figure out how to do things correctly, but once you have that figured out all peripherals work in a similar way.